# awk doesn't print simple field

Tags: awk

Here is a little awk script

```
> # cat zzz.awk
FS=" "
/fruit/ { fr = $2; print $fr; }
```

applied on this data file

```
> # cat data.dat

fruit apple 1 3
fruit mango 4 9
vegetable tomato 6 5
fruit orange 9 8
vegetable potato 1 4
```

, producing this output:

```
> # awk   -f zzz.awk   data.dat

fruit apple 1 3
fruit apple 1 3
fruit mango 4 9
fruit mango 4 9
vegetable tomato 6 5
fruit orange 9 8
fruit orange 9 8
vegetable potato 1 4
```

Why it doesn't produce instead, this expected output

```
apple
mango
orange
```

, and how to correct the script?

(Current version is GNU Awk 3.1.7, even if a portable solution is preferred.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that awk is just plain wrong. For example, `FS` can't be set like that, it would output every record:

```
$ awk 'FS=" "' file
fruit apple 1 3
fruit mango 4 9
vegetable tomato 6 5
fruit orange 9 8
vegetable potato 1 4
```

Use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}' file
```

Next, you don't reference variables as `$fr` in awk (unless that's what you are after). That evaluates to `$0` and you print the whole record which explains the duplicated records in your output. So, to wrap it up:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=" " } 
$1 == "fruit" { fr=$2; print fr }' file
apple
mango
orange
```

(or just `awk '/^fruit/{print $2}'` file)

Answer (score 1):

All awk scripts are composed of sections that share the same structure:

```
PATTERN { CODE }
```

Yours does not. Use the special pattern `BEGIN` to do things you want to do at the start. Furthermore, variables in `awk` do not mandatorily have the `$` glyph. `$2` is `$2`, but `fr` is just `fr`.

```
BEGIN { FS=" " }
/fruit/ { fr = $2; print fr; }
```

Of course, you can just do:

```
awk -F' ' '$1=="fruit"{print $2}' data.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

With this small awk code, you can use it inline like this:

```
awk -F" " '/fruit/ {print $2}' data.dat
apple
mango
orange
```

But you do not need to set field separator to space, just leave it out and it should work. (NB then tab will be included)

```
awk '/fruit/ {print $2}' data.dat
apple
mango
orange
```

Answer (score -1):

try following

```
echo "fruit apple 1 3
fruit apple 1 3
fruit mango 4 9
fruit mango 4 9
vegetable tomato 6 5
fruit orange 9 8
fruit orange 9 8
vegetable potato 1 4" |awk '{print $2}' | uniq
```

Comment: Please add a comment explaining how your code fixes the issue to improve this answer.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Updated a sample command to test the changes. See if that helps.